# Blasts of hot water in Shower

Tags: plumbing, water, shower, pump

[image]Why do i get Hot water during the shower every time the pump kicks on? Every time I am in the shower and the pump kicks in to build pressure, the water gets very hot and stays that way until the pressure is built up and the pump tuns off.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We can't tell from here; perhaps if you include a diagram of your water system (pump, pressure tank, heater, shower) we could be more useful to you.

Comment: What pump? Is this water from a well?

Comment: This is a well.  I have added a diagram.  The pressure tank is just T'ed into the cold water line at the shower as shown.

Comment: Looks to me like the pressure from the pressure tank and the well would be additive on all the plumbing *except* for the tub/shower cold supply, based on its position. But I'm not a plumber or a physicist, so I'll let a real expert confirm or refute.